# Move objects in a specific location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to move the object to a specific location I used the below code, but after releasing the mouse, the position changed to a different position.
So what I'm trying to do is, forklift picks up object and places it in specific place.

Does anybody know where I am going wrong or have another idea?

```
public GameObject item;
public GameObject tempParent;
public Transform guide;

void Start()
{
    item.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    item.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
    item.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
    item.transform.position = guide.transform.position;
    item.transform.rotation = guide.transform.rotation;
    item.transform.parent = tempParent.transform;
}
private void OnMouseUp()
{
    float horizontalInput = 24.63001f;
    float verticalInput = 1.017074f;
    item.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
    item.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
    transform.position = new Vector3(horizontalInput, verticalInput, 23.95186f);
}
```

Comment: Please tag the environment you’re doing this in. C# versions don’t matter, the libraries etc used do since this isn’t anything built in to .NET

Comment: Is this Unity or something else? I'm sure you don't need a specific C# version, please tag your question as [c#] and whatever framework you are using.

Comment: Note that C# is not UnityScript. UnityScript is a flavour of JavaScript created for Unity.

Comment: oh ok thnq i will update it